# How to delete last comma from appended query string

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Okay, if you read the title, that is a good sign.  I'm getting my feet wet in some areas I'm not too familiar with here.

To save everyone time from reading, I have a series of checkboxes (named appropriately):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="5"> C<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="6"> C+<br />
```

I am able to save one checkbox value to MySQLi DB by appending the values to the original query.   When `$max == 1`.

When I add a second value, I need to add a comma in between the values being added.  So, I do that when the `$max > 1`.

I thought I could simply delete the last comma from the query string and the MySQL would work.  However, the substr function does not delete the comma / or anything.  I simply need to figure out a way to delete the last comma when I have more than one row of values being entered.

Here is my code:

```
  $query= "INSERT INTO individual_skills(Skills_ID,Ind_ID) VALUES ";
  $max = sizeof($skills);
  for ($i=0; $i<$max;$i++) {   
       if ($max == 1) { 
            // appending the query above with the values
            $query.= " (" .$skills[$i]. ",".$_SESSION['Ind_ID'].")";    
           } // END IF MAX == 1  

        if ($max > 1) {  
            // appending the query above with the values
            // same query as above except note the comma at the end for the MySQL query
            $query.= " (" .$skills[$i]. ",".$_SESSION['Ind_ID']."),";
            substr($query,0,-1);        
        } // END IF MAX > 1

  }   // END FOR LOOP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thinking and `substr` is exactly correct, but you're not actually using the return value of it. All you need to do is put the return value back into `$query`.

```
$query = substr($query, 0, -1);
```

You could also try this, which alleviates the need for the `substr` all together by simply not adding the comma on the last entry in the first place.

```
$query= "INSERT INTO individual_skills(Skills_ID,Ind_ID) VALUES ";
$max = sizeof($skills);
for ($i=0; $i < $max; $i++)
{
    $query .= " (" . $skills[$i] . ", " . $_SESSION['Ind_ID'] . ")";
    if ($max > 1 && $max != ($i+1))
        $query .= ",";
}
```

Comment: Now I'm so close.  That removed all of the commas from my end...Not the last one.  So close.  Any suggestions how to just remove the last comma?

Comment: @kentrenholm Simply move it down under `// END FOR LOOP`, and in an `if($max > 1) { }` statement :)

Comment: So it looks like this:  VALUES (21,10), (22,10) and not VALUES (21,10) (22,10)

Comment: WOW!  I'm going to be late for class but your help and guidance got this to work in minutes.  I said in my head: There is no one this smart -- you are a genius.  So much appreciate your help.  It works.  Celebration!!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of crazy `str_replace` or `if` statement, you can use an array and then [`implode`](http://php.net/implode) it to have a nice string:

```
$query      = "INSERT INTO individual_skills (Skills_ID, Ind_ID) VALUES ";
$max        = sizeof($skills);
$parameters = array();

for ($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {
    $parameters[] = " (" .$skills[$i]. ", ".$_SESSION['Ind_ID'].")";
}

$query .= implode(', ', $parameters);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
substr($query,0,-1);
```

to

```
$query = rtrim($query, ",")
```

[`rtrim` removes characters from the end of a string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) and it **returns** a value

You also need to move it to the end of the loop, you could remove the code duplication too ->

```
$max = sizeof($skills);
for ($i=0; $i<$max;$i++) {   
  $query.= " (" .$skills[$i]. ",".$_SESSION['Ind_ID'].")";      
  if ($max > 1) {
     $query .= ",";
  } // CLOSE IF
}   // END FOR LOOP
// Now remove the last comma if required
if ($max > 1) { 
   $query = rtrim($query, ",");
}
```

Comment: I tried that as well.  Did not work.  I think it might be treating my query different somehow.

Comment: @kentrenholm try that now - it should be out of the loop

Answer (score 2):

Your code suffers from too much repetitions.
It actually can be written short and consize way
and it suffers from SQL injection too

```
$query = "INSERT INTO individual_skills VALUES ";
$comma = '';
foreach($skills as $skill) {
    $skill = intval($skill);
    $indid = intval($_SESSION['Ind_ID']);
    $query.= "$comma ($skill, $indid)";
    $comma = ',';    
}
```

it is short both in terms of processor cycles and written code.

> However, the substr function does not delete the comma / or anything.

it does. You just using it wrong way. Yo need to assign it's result to a variable. A manual page always helps.

Answer (score 2):

What i would do is use the php implode() function for this kind of things.
This is how i would do it:

```
$query= "INSERT INTO individual_skills(Skills_ID,Ind_ID) VALUES ";
$value_array = array();
foreach($skills as $skill) {
    $value_array[] = "(" .$skill. ",".$_SESSION['Ind_ID'].")";
}
$query = "INSERT INTO individual_skills(Skills_ID,Ind_ID) VALUES ". implode(', ', $value_array);
```

Comment: So, what's the difference with my answer then? :)

Comment: except the foreach, which is just a matter of taste.
Yours was posted while I was typing, what makes you faster than me.
I guess that's the only difference... ;-)

Comment: It is not matter of taste though, but rather of cleaner code. However, the very idea of string-to-array-and-back-to-string conversion is not that clear.

Comment: I do agree with you that a foreach provides cleaner code than normal for loops. The whole point in the conversion is to not worry about things that can be taken care of by PHP itself. It might be slower, (didn't test it) and it takes more memory for sure (tested with common sense). But if you need to make that optimization over the better readability the implode provides, I do believe that there's something more essentially wrong with the code or setup of the project.